# Is IronPython usable as a replacement for CPython?

Tags: python, ironpython, dynamic-language-runtime, cpython

Has IronPython gotten to a point where you can just drop it in as a replacement for CPython?

To clarify: I mean can IronPython run applications originally written for CPython (no .NET involved, of course)

Comment: A little besides the point, but I'm curious: If your applications don't involve .Net, is there a good reason why you would want to?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, pretty much, at least on Windows with "real" (Microsoft) .NET underneath.  If you're depending on C-coded extensions, chances are that [ironclad](http://code.google.com/p/ironclad/) can bail you out; you get 2.6 support, just about every CPython standard library or third-party extension module (maybe not trivial for those coded in Fortran, or C++, but that's a minority), plus of course every .NET module on the planet -- not a bad tradeoff!

How well this works with Mono on MacOSX or Linux is a different issue...

Answer (score 3):

It has been tested to work well with mono on Linux and I use it regularly to open up opportunities to use  - as Alex Martelli so eloquently put it - "every .NET module on the planet".

I have faced some troubles in accessing third party extension modules, but that has pretty much always been a path issue, which is easy to correct.

I don't know how well this works on a Mac, though.

Comment: Yep, that's been my (modest, limited) experience too -- as long as you're on Windows with real .NET, bliss; with Mono on Mac or Linux, well, maybe, perhaps, if you're lucky;-). So if you care about cross-platform, at this time, I'd think twice; if you're bought into MSFT's gospel of Windows-only, hey, go for it -- IronPython's the best Windows-only language in the galaxy today!-)

Answer (score -1):

Ironpython have some prolbems to replace the cpython，like
Base on cpy, you can use some libs directly, but, in ipy, you must use ironclad, and the effiencency is insufferable.
And, if you want use py files, there will be many errors, even if you use same gramma.
So, there are two different things, only same gramma.

Its only the merit is to be load by .net easily.

Comment: -1 "so many prolbems" is a tiny bit vague, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: @cschol：I am so sorry to criticize ipy, but I persevere my opnion! Ironpython and cpython are two different things, only use same gramma. That's why ipy must use ironclad to use python file or code! I only want to tell joemoe, how to choose ipy or cpy! But, someone seems disagree with me.

Comment: no reason to be sorry. The downvote was not for your opinion, but the way you stated it. If you think ipy has problems it would be nice to list those in your answer instead of just saying "it has many problems".